# Is this the best way to sum decimal value types in queries?

Tags: f#

I was getting an error when I was execting the following query that summed a non-nullable decimal. The magnitude was null when there was no magnitude value for a location/organization combination.

```
let q = query { from m in Measure do
                  where (locations.Contains(m.Location) 
                         && organizations.Contains(m.Organization))
                  sumBy m.Magnitude }
```

Error: The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Decimal which is a non-nullable value type.

I solved this in the following way. Is this there a better way to do this?

```
let convert (n:Nullable<decimal>) =
        let c:decimal = 0M
        if n.HasValue then n.Value else c

let q = query { from m in Measure do
                  let nullable = Nullable<decimal>(m.Magnitude)
                  where (locations.Contains(m.Location) 
                         && organizations.Contains(m.Organization))
                  sumBy (convert(nullable)) }
```

Thanks. I changed my query to the following.

```
query {  for m in db.Measurement do
                let nullable = Nullable<decimal>(m.Magnitude)
                where ( m.Measure = me 
                        && (if slice.Organization > 0L then organizationUnits.Contains( m.PrimalOrganizationUnit.Value ) else true)
                        && (if slice.Location > 0L then locationUnits.Contains(m.PrimalLocationUnit.Value) else true) )
                sumByNullable (nullable) }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[sumByNullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh324035%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 3):

This is a LINQ-to-SQL issue (but is by design, since in SQL summing an empty column results in NULL, see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/479f2823-c942-4990-adca-21e03f969a12/)), not specific to F#.  Your workaround seems to match the suggestion in the linked MSDN Forums thread.